# php Array does not delete row with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, foreach

After I modified the Array index Quantity to change the minus button to delete button when value of the input = 1 but something is wrong and it does not delete
I want to hide the old button for the modification but cant get the new button to submit the form.
Maybe it sounds stupid but as a designer I tryed my best so if someone can see this clearer pls help to correct

[image]

---

PHP SECTION

```
<?php
    // REMOVE ITEM
    if (isset($_POST['index_to_remove']) && $_POST['index_to_remove'] != "") {
        // Access the array and run code to remove that array index
        $key_to_remove = $_POST['index_to_remove'];
        if (count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) <= 1) {
            unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
        } else {
            unset($_SESSION["cart_array"][$key_to_remove]);
            sort($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
        }
        exit;
    }
    ?>

if ($each_item['quantity'] == 1) {
            $fa_icon = 'fas fa-trash-alt';
            $operation = 'delete_item';
        } else {
            $fa_icon = 'fa fa-minus';
            $operation = 'minusbot';
        }
        

$action = '<button style="width:45px" 
                               type="button" 
            onclick="return update_qty(' . $key_of_session . ',\'' . $operation . '\'),submit()" 
class="btn-subtract btn btn-primary">
                <i class="' . $fa_icon . '"></i>
            </button>';

    $html .= '<form id="form_id_' . $key_of_session . '">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <button style="width:45px" 
                        type="button" 
                        class="btn-add btn btn-primary" 
                        onclick="return update_qty(' . $key_of_session . 
                                 ',\'plusbot\')">
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
            </div>
            <input id="kilohere_' . $key_of_session . '" 
                   class="form-control counter" 
                   onchange="return submit_form(' . "'#form_id_" 
                            .$key_of_session ."'". ')" 
                   data-min="1" 
                   max="99" 
                   name="quantity" 
                   type="text" 
                   value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '" 
                   size="1" 
                   maxlength="2" />
              <div class="input-group-append">' . $action .'</div>
        <input name="item_to_adjust" 
               type="hidden" 
               value="' . $item_id . '" />
        <input name="size" 
               type="hidden" 
               value="' . $size . '" />
        <input name="key_of_session" 
               type="hidden" 
               value="' . $key_of_session . '">
        </form>';
```

HTML SECTION OF OLD BUTTON

---

```
// DELETEBUTTON
        $cartOutput .= '
        <td style="border-right:1px solid #0275d8; 
               border-top:1px dotted #BBBBBB ; 
               text-align:center;">
            <form id="form_delete_'.$key_of_session.'">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"  onclick="return submit_form(' ."'#form_delete_". $key_of_session . "'". ',\'true\');">
                    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                </button>
                <input name="index_to_remove" type="hidden" value="' . $key_of_session . '" />
                <input name="item_id" type="hidden" value="' . $item_id . '" />
            </form>
        </td>';
```

JAVASCRIPT

---

```
// JS

<script>
                function update_qty(id, operation) {
                    let inputField = document.getElementById('kilohere_' + id);
                    let input_value = inputField.value;
                    let post = false;
                    if (operation == 'minusbot' && input_value > 1) {
                        inputField.value = parseInt(inputField.value) - 1;
                        post = true;
                    } else if (operation == 'plusbot' && input_value < 50) {
                        inputField.value = parseInt(inputField.value) + 1;
                        post = true;
                    } else if (operation == 'delete_item') {
                        //DO THE OPERATION HERE
                        var form = document.getElementById("form-id");
                        document.getElementById("your-id").addEventListener("click", function() {
                            form.submit();
                        });
                    }
                    if (post == true) {
                        let form_name = '#form_id_' + id;
                        submit_form(form_name);
                    }
                }

                function submit_form(form_name,delete_item = "false") {
                    let form = document.querySelector(form_name);
                    let form_data = new FormData(form);
                    console.log(form_name)
                    console.log(form_data)
                    var url = 'cart.php';
                    fetch(url, {
                            method: 'POST',
                            body: form_data,
                        })
                        .then(response => response.text()) // response.json() for json data
                        .then(data => {
                            console.log(data)
                            if (delete_item != "false"){
                                window.location.href = window.location;
                            }
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            console.error('Error:', error);
                        });
                }
            </script>
```

Comment: Where is the code that changes minus to delete?

Comment: After the first php, it is a if condition and after that the botton is there

Comment: `document.getElementById("your-id").addEventListener("click", function() { form.submit(); });` doesn't submit the form. It says that the next time the user clicks on the `your-id` button, the form will be submitted.

Comment: How would be the right way to submit this time?

Comment: Just use `form.submit()`

Comment: Ok still did not delete from new button, but the old button does.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235980/discussion-between-said-and-barmar).